# how to js call function and access caller parameters

Tags: javascript

```
function caller(id){
    accessParam()
}

function accessParam() {
    // access caller param without passing
    if(id){
        // do something
    }
}

// execute caller function
caller(1001)
```

Is there a posible way to access without passing paramter `accessParam()`

Comment: Only if you define `acc[ess]Param` *inside* `caller`, so it closes over `id`. Could you give some *context* - what's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Another idea is to use a getter and setter function to pass it.

Comment: " without passing parameter" no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a posible way to access without passing paramter `accessParam()`

No, there isn't. `id` is a local variable within `caller()`, and there's no way to access local variables from outside the function.

And even if there were, it would be very poor design, since it would mean that `accParam()` could only be used from that function. The general idea of functions is that they should operate independently.

Passing parameters and returning values is the cornerstone of abstraction in programming.